# Uploaded Image's Path is Broken in ASP.NET - unable to show Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, relative-path

Previously I successfully showed Image like this:

> ```
>         <img class="centered" src="~/Content/images/gif.gif" style="max-height:12vw;" />
> ```

with no problem, but this image was added to the Solution's images folder.

However, when I upload image to API like and store it like this:

```
string FileName = valueobject.PictureName;
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/" + valueobject.PictureOwner + "/");
        string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, FileName);

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, valueobject.PictureImage);
            //store UserFile with path to the image
            UserFile _userFile = new UserFile();
            _userFile.FileOwner = valueobject.PictureOwner;
            string relativePath = "~/UserFiles/" + valueobject.PictureOwner + "/";
            string imgRelativePath = Path.Combine(relativePath, FileName);
            _userFile.FilePath = imgRelativePath;
```

The image is saved - the folder is created and image is saved correctly in localhost.

However I am unable to resolve the relative path in MVC when I try:

```
                        <img height="400" style="width:auto" src="@Model.HomeGalleries[g].GalleryImageStrings[i]" runat="server" />
```

I get "broken" image icon even that

> @Model.HomeGalleries[g].GalleryImageStrings[i]
>   is equal to 
>   imgRelativePath

I am not sure why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you must include Server.MapPath for this actual image path. folloing below this line ,like as.

```
string relativePath = Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/" + valueobject.PictureOwner + "/");
```

please try this.hopefully this you help.